# jQuery.validate - valid() failing unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery validate plugin.  I have this code:

```
$(".btn-overview-basic-save").click(function(e) {
    if (!$('.contact-overview').valid()) {
    } else {
        alert("invalid")
    }
```

And I'm getting the invalid alert for some reason, even though the form is filled out, and no errors or error markup are showing up.  I commented out all of my rules, and I still get it.  I tried adding:

```
errorPlacement: function ($error, $element) {
    console.log("error", $error, $element);
}
```

But nothing shows up in my console.

Short of grabbing a non-minified version of the validate plugin and stepping through, what's the best way to figure out what's going on here?

Comment: I love this plugin but it sure is particular. I've run into this a couple times but it was for a different reason each time..

Comment: @ngmiceli - any half-thoughts you can come up with - just dump 'em in a comment and I'd be much appreciative.

Comment: Wait, isn't your if case backwards? If its not valid, do nothing, else (it is valid) but alert invalid?

Comment: @ngmiceli - you spotted it - throw it up ...

Comment: My favorite part of Software Engineering. Missing single characters and fretting over it for hours. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just the case of some backwards logic. Did you miss the `!` in front of `.valid()`?

```
if (! $('.contact-overview').valid()) //if it is not valid
{
      //Handle INVALID logic here
} 
else  //if it is valid
{
    alert("invalid")  //handle VALID logic here. Wait...
}
```

Remove the `!` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Here the issue `if (!$('.contact-overview').valid())` it should be
 `if ( $('.contact-overview').valid() )` without    **!**

```
$(".btn-overview-basic-save").click(function(e) {
    if ( $('.contact-overview').valid() ) {
    } else {
        alert("invalid")
    }
```

Comment: what should i do, the solution is this only and till that the answer was not accepted ... :)

Comment: No worries - I'm not allowed to accept an answer until 15 minutes after I ask - that's why it wasn't accepted yet.